# Apache Beam - Delta between windows

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

*Apologies*, in trying to be concise and clear my previous description of my question turned into a special case of the general case I'm trying to solve.

**New Description**

I'm trying to Compare the last emitted value of an Aggregation Function (Let's say Sum()) with a each element that I aggregate over in the current window.

[image]

**Worth noting, that the ideal (I think) solution would include**

- The T2(from t-1) element used at time = t is the one that was created during the previous window.

I've been playing with several ideas/experiments but I'm struggling to find a way to accomplish this in a way is elegant and "empathetic" to Beam's compute model (which I'm still trying to fully Grock after many an article/blog/doc and book :)

Side inputs seem unwieldy because It looks like I have to shift the emitted 5M@T-1 Aggregation's timestamp into the 5M@T's window in order to align it with the current 5M window

In attempting this with side inputs (as I understand them), I ended up with some nasty code that was quite "circularly referential", but not in an elegant recursive way :)

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
Modified diagram and improved description to more clearly show:

- the intent of using emitted T2(from t-1) to calculate T2 at t
- that the desired T2(from t-1) used to calculate T2 is the one with the correct key

Comment: According to the new updated description, it could be interesting to consider an strategy revolving around panes instead of windows. As you have said, attempts to feed the previously emitted output into the current window will most likely end up creating a cycle. Something along the lines of using a global window and set a trigger with discardingFiredPanes() as the accumulation mode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the timestamp of records that are materialized so that they appear in the current window, you should supply a window mapping fn which just maps the current window on to the past one.
You'll want to create a custom [WindowFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/5cb3969b53ce7fecb33b347c7113602957f5ee9f/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/WindowFn.java#L50) which implements the window mapping behavior that you want paying special attention to overriding the [getDefaultWindowMappingFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/5cb3969b53ce7fecb33b347c7113602957f5ee9f/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/WindowFn.java#L152) function.

Your pipeline would be like:

```
PCollection<T> mySource = /* data */
PCollectionView<SumT> view = mySource
    .apply(Window.into(myCustomWindowFnWithNewWindowMappingFn))
    .apply(Combine.globally(myCombiner).asSingletonView());

mySource.apply(ParDo.of(/* DoFn that consumes side input */).withSideInputs(view));
```

Pay special attention to the default value the combiner will produce since this will be the default value when the view has had no data emitted to it.
Also, the easiest way to write your own custom window function is to copy an existing one.

Comment: Thanks!

I'll play with this tomorrow.

In case you have a second before I explore further:

If I'm understanding correctly:

1. we are applying a "different" transform (a reduction) on mySource, that turns the PCollection<T> into a PCollectionView<SumT> (with the windowing now correct)
2. the DoFn that uses the side input produces a PCollection<NotNeccesarily_SumT>

I'll need to play a bit more, but:
1) is it possible to re-use the value from the DoFn@T-1 at T? 
2) will it be with the correct Key (if using asSingletonView())

Am I missing anything?

**Updated Question**